# Что такое враппер?

Tags: c#

Как я понял враппер может быть нужен чтобы например использовать библиотеку, написанную на СИ, в программе на C#. 
Враппер это отдельный файл от библиотеки?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrapper переводится как "обёртка". Поскольку я не вижу смысла использовать лишние англицизмы, предпочту переведённый термин.

Обёртка требуется, если одна подсистема требует реализации определённого интерфейса, а другая подсистема, в которой реализована нужная функциональность, не реализует этот интерфейс. Тогда пишется легковесный класс, реализующий требуемый интерфейс и делегирующий вызовы методов этого интерфейса второй подсистеме. После этого первой подсистеме передаётся этот класс, благодаря которому она может работать со второй подсистемой через свой родной интерфейс.

Например, в .NET есть абстракция "поток", представленная базовым абстрактным классом Stream. Эта абстракция используется такими подсистемами, как, например, сериализаторы. А дальше мы можем, отнаследовавшись от класса Stream, реализовать потоковый доступ к любому источнику данных, и тогда любой сериализатор будет работать с этим источником данных через интерфейс потока.

"Библиотека на C" является частным случаем второй подсистемы. В этом случае оборачивать требуется сам механизм взаимодействия: для неуправляемых библиотек основным способом внешнего взаимодействия являются экспортируемые функции, а для управляемых - публичные типы. Обёртка над C-библиотекой помещается в .NET-среду, и работа с библиотекой происходит через обращение к .NET-типу, который, как минимум, должен содержать методы, импортированные из библиотеки (без тела, с модификатором extern и атрибутом DllImport). Если требуется какая-либо дополнительная обработка, то импортированные методы следует сделать приватными, а наружу вывести методы, вызывающие импортированные и делающие вспомогательную работу.

Answer (score 3):

Враппер это обертщик некоторой функциональности, конкретный класс или член класса, который будет оборачивать функции чего-либо для использования в другой среде, например.

Конкретнее: если тебе, предположим, нужно использовать какую-либо из функций WinAPI при помощи P/Invoke ты должен написать метод, который сделает вызов этой функции, обработает исключения и выходные данные этой функции. В таком случае говорят, что это метод-враппер для функции WinAPI